# Laravel collection not properly sort

Tags: php, laravel

I try to sort my collection using Laravel function.

here is my data for example:

```
$collection = 
 [
  {
    "total_earned": "31739",
    "total_spent": "0",
    "total_amount": "317390",
    "date": "2015-10-01"
  }, {
    "total_earned": "212622",
    "total_spent": "86943",
    "total_amount": "2213165",
    "date": "2015-12-01"
  }, {
    "total_earned": 0,
    "total_spent": 0,
    "total_amount": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-29"
  }, {
    "total_earned": 0,
    "total_spent": 0,
    "total_amount": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-30"
  }
];
```

When I try to sort using Laravel `sortBy` function and return it become like this:

```
[{
    "total_earned": 0,
    "total_spent": 0,
    "total_amount": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-29"
}, {
    "total_earned": 0,
    "total_spent": 0,
    "total_amount": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-30"
}, {
    "total_earned": "212622",
    "total_spent": "86943",
    "total_amount": "2213165",
    "date": "2015-12-01"
}, {
    "total_earned": "31739",
    "total_spent": "0",
    "total_amount": "317390",
    "date": "2015-10-01"
}]
```

As you can see date `2015-10-01` is at bottom. It supposed to be before `2015-10-29`.

My code to sort:

`return $transaction->sortBy('date')->values()->all();`

Is this a bug or the sort suppose to be like that?

---

Update my entire code:

```
$transaction = Transaction::dateRange($startDate->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->groupBy('merchant_branch_id', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
                ->selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as date, SUM(point_earned) as total_earned, SUM(point_spent) as total_spent,
                FLOOR(SUM(amount)) as total_amount')
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->get();

$convert = $transaction->map(function($item, $key) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d');

    return [$date];
});

$convert = $convert->toArray();
$period = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $endDate);
foreach ($period as $row) {
    $date = $row->format('Y-m-d');

    if (!in_array_r($date, $convert)) {
        $transaction->push(['date' => $date, 'total_earned' => 0, 'total_spent' => 0, 'total_amount' => 0]);
    }
}
$sorted = $transaction->sortBy('date')->values()->all();
return $sorted;
```

Comment: You mean that it actually ___changes___ the dates in the collection? There's a `2015-11-29` in the before, but not in the after).... That's a pretty fundamental bug, or you're showing us incorrect before/after data.... one or the other

Comment: Here is the correct one. my mistake.

Comment: I just tried it using your data and it worked fine. Seems like there's something else going on. You'll need to show more of your code.

Comment: @patricus I've update with my code

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else arrives at this question with the same problem, you can try with the following code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36170075/1208242:

```
$sorted = $transaction->sortBy(function($col)
{
    return $col;
})->values()->all();
```

It might give you the dates in the wrong order (sortBy sorts in 'ascending' order by default, which apparently returns descending order when working with dates on Y-m-d format), so you could use `sortByDesc()` method instead