# Laravel sort collection by date

Tags: php, laravel

I have this collection result:

```
$result = [{
    "date": "2016-03-21",
    "total_earned": "101214.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03-22",
    "total_earned": "94334.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03-23",
    "total_earned": "96422.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-02-23",
    "total_earned": 0
},
{
    "date": "2016-02-24",
    "total_earned": 0
},
{
    "date": "2016-02-25",
    "total_earned": 0
}]
```

I want to sort the result by date:

```
$sorted = $transaction->sortBy('date')->values()->all();
```

But I don't get the expected result:

```
[{
    "date": "2016-02-23",
    "total_earned": 0

},
{
    "date": "2016-02-24",
    "total_earned": 0
},
{
    "date": "2016-02-25",
    "total_earned": 0
},
{
    "date": "2016-03-22",
    "total_earned": "94334.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03-21",
    "total_earned": "101214.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03-23",
    "total_earned": "96422.00"
}]
```

As you can see all with month 2 is sort properly. However at month 3 it start messed up. (the real result is longer than this and it messed up start at month 3)

Any solution to make it sort properly?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the type of column `date` have?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Hi. date type is string

Comment: Does `orderBy('date', 'ASC')` work?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyMezenin I'm using this method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby . I've tried yours but method not found. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this using [sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby):

```php
$sorted = $transaction->sortBy(function($col) {
    return $col;
})->values()->all();
```

Comment: It works!. but i need to remove `->date` to make it working. If not it will return me `trying to get property of non object`

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I created this macro.

```
Collection::macro('sortByDate', function (string $column = 'created_at', bool $descending = true) {
/* @var $this Collection */
return $this->sortBy(function ($datum) use ($column) {
    return strtotime(((object)$datum)->$column);
}, SORT_REGULAR, $descending);
```

});

I use it like this:

```
$comments = $job->comments->merge($job->customer->comments)->sortByDate('created_at', true);
```

Comment: This is a clean solution in my eyes. I used a similar solution here on my project :))

Answer (score -10):

You may try

```
$transaction->groupBy('date');
```

And be sure that $transaction is a collection;

Comment: Hi, If i group it, it become seperated array. and it not sorted